# how to insert a string in the middle after a symbol in Databricks SQL?

Tags: databricks-sql

i have a column with string values as 'AAA-BBB-XXX'. How do i insert a string 'ZZZ-' after the last hyphen in Databricks SQL

Input string : 'AAA-BBB-XXX'

Output string : 'AAA-BBB-ZZZ-XXX'